# ts-node-dev: no script to run provided when using dotenv

Tags: typescript, dotenv, ts-node, ts-node-dev

I have a script in `package.json` that runs as expected when using the standard `.env` file.

```
"scripts": {
  "commands": "ts-node-dev --files deploy-commands.ts",
},
```

but when I try specify a different .env file (`.env.prod`)

```
"scripts": {
  "commands": "dotenv -e .env.prod ts-node-dev --files deploy-commands.ts",
},
```

I get the error:

```
ts-node-dev: no script to run provided
```

Answer (score 5):

According to [the dotenv-cli documentation](https://github.com/entropitor/dotenv-cli#flags-to-the-underlying-command) you'll need to use `--` if you want to pass flags to the inner command. In your case, the following should work:

```
dotenv -e .env.prod -- ts-node-dev --files deploy-commands.ts
```